# few questions about the principals of redux

Tags: redux

I read few tutorials about redux, but I still have some questions about redux:

1) if the reducers do not mutate the state, but return a new state, how does the new information is being kept?

2) what is the most recommended place to hold API requests back to the server when I change the data? the reducers? the store? or maybe other place?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3):

In your reducers you always copy the current state and only update the cloned one. Usually you will see a spread operator:

```
return { ...state, foo: 'new foo' }
```

If we make it step by step:

```
const newState = { ...state } // copy the current state
newState.foo = 'new foo'
return newState
```

you can also use `Object.assign()` to copy the state:

```
const newState = Object.assign({}, state)
```

All other information will be kept because the new state is always copied from the previous state.

API requests are usually handled in action creators. Since they are asynchronous you will need middleware to handle them, like [redux-thunk](https://github.com/gaearon/redux-thunk).

Reducers should be pure and synchronous, you should never send API requests in a reducer. If you are using React another place to call the API is your component. It's totally fine to do that especially you are working on a small app. But most of the time you want to separate the UI and the logic, that's why we use action creators.

For asynchronous action creators you can take a look at this chapter: http://redux.js.org/docs/advanced/AsyncActions.html